# Why can an array be compared with ">="?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been playing around with JavaScript and I ended up seeing code like this:

```js
console.log([123, 1] >= 213)
// --> false
```

Why can this even be executed? What does it do? Will it always be false?

Comment: What is this *meant* to do?

Comment: Python and JavaScript are **completely** different languages.

Comment: Why does this execute? Also I was just playing around with javascript.

Comment: Bringing up Python is a distraction. I edited the question to focus on JavaScript, the oddball language.

Comment: @JJCauton Because the [spec](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan) says so. And yes, the Python spec says something different. That’s mainly because ECMAScript and Python have _absolutely nothing to do_ with each other.